# Python3 daemon library

Tags: python-3.4, python-daemon

I'm learning Python3, especially the daemon library. I want my daemon to be called with two possible arguments : start & stop.

So far I have this code :

```
def start():
  with context:
    pidfile = open(Config.WDIR+scriptname+".pid",'w')
    pidfile.write(str(getpid()))
    pidfile.close()
    feed_the_db()

def stop(pid):
  try:
    kill(int(pid),15)
  except ProcessLookupError:
    print("Nothing to kill… (No process with PID "+pid+")")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  scriptname = sys.argv[0]
  context = daemon.DaemonContext(
  working_directory=Config.WDIR,
  pidfile=lockfile.FileLock(Config.WDIR+scriptname),
  stdout=sys.stdout,
  stderr=sys.stderr)
  try:
    if sys.argv[1] == 'start':
      start()
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'stop':
      try:
        pidfile = open(Config.WDIR+scriptname+".pid",'r')
        pid = pidfile.read()
        pidfile.close()
        remove(name+".pid")
        print(name+" (PID "+pid+")")
        stop(pid)
      except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Nothing to kill… ("+scriptname+".pid not found)")
    else:
      print("\nUnknown option : "+sys.argv[1]+"\n\nUsage "+sys.argv[0]+" <start|stop>\n")   
  except IndexError:
    print("\nUsage "+sys.argv[0]+" <start|stop>\n")
```

It's working but I wonder if I'm doing it the right way.

In particular, why do I have to manually store the PID. Why is it not already contained in the automatically created file :

```
myhostname-a6982700.3392-7990643415029806679
```

or the lock file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up the daemon script and the code responsible for managing it.

Usually in say Ubuntu for example you would control this via upstart

```
description "Some Description"
author "your@email-address.com"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

exec /path/to/script
```

The actual running python application would never need to store its pid because it always has access to it.

So what are writing is a script that essentially manages daemon processes , is that really what you want?

PS: do yourself a favour and get to know the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some Description')
parser.add_argument('command', help='Either stop or start', choices=['start', 'stop'])

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.command)
```

It is well worth it

Comment: Thank for your answer Anarci. Yes this is really what I want. The reason why I don’t want to relay on Upstart, or let's say systemd, is that I want the script to be platform agnostic… I'm only at the protoype stage, for sure I'll try to separate the daemon managment from the actual treatment in my final program… I'll have a look at the argparse library.

I'm astonished by the quick response I got here (it was my first post here), SO rocks for sure ! 

Have a nice day.

Comment: I see, in that case you definitely need some way to pass the pid from the process to the management script. I would define a directory where all running scripts write a file named with their pid and on shutdown they then delete this file. This would be unrelated to the daemon stuff.